# Exercises related to Maximum modulus theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

[image]

and the following is a hint from same book

[image]

I’d like to know why we should consider $f_n(z)$ instead of $f(z)$. Is there an advantage of considering such auxiliary function?

And also on the circle $C$, at $\zeta =1$, we don ‘t know whether $f$ is analytic or not, but the author says that $ |F_n(z)| \lt \varepsilon$ for all $\zeta \in C$.

Should it be $C-{1}$ instead of $C$?

Thank you for your comment in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MMP is applied to the circle $C$. By hypothesis there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\zeta \in C$ and $|\zeta -1| <\delta$ implies $|F(z)| <\epsilon$. Now consider points $\zeta \in C$ with $|\zeta -1| \geq \delta$. If you draw a picture of the two circles you will notice immediately that $|\zeta|$ stays away from $1$. Hence $|\zeta|^{n} \to 0$ uniformly for $\zeta \in C$ and $|\zeta -1| \geq \delta$ Hence we can make $|F(\zeta)| <\epsilon$ by choosing $n$ sufficiently large. The reason for considering $F$ should now be clear.

Comment: Thank you. Is "No" mis-typor for "Now", right?

Comment: @glimpser Yes, of course. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: I have one more question, why we should consider points more than $\delta$ away from $1$? As far as, if we make it close to $1$ less than $\delta$, then $|\zeta -1| \lt \delta$ guarantees that $|f(\zeta)| \lt \varepsilon$, where am I wrong?

Comment: the implication above I've written only holds for $\zeta \in C$, that's what I'm missing, isn't it?

Comment: @glimpser Yes, that is right,

Comment: then should it be $\zeta$ in inside the circle $C$ other than $\zeta \in C$?

Comment: @glimpser If $|F(\zeta)| <\epsilon$ for $\zeta$ on $C$ then $|F(\zeta)| \leq \epsilon$ for $\zeta$ inside $C$ by MMP.

Comment: But as fas as I know, if you want to apply MMP, the function should be continuous on the closure of domain, but in this case, the closure of domain contains 1. What am I missing.

Comment: @glimpser Your point is valid. But the standard trick it to apply MMP to $|\zeta -\frac 1 2| \leq \frac 1 2-\epsilon$ and then let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Ahha.... I see now. Thank you for kind answers...

Comment: Sorry to comment again, I thought I get it, but I wasn’t. For $|\zeta - \frac{1}{2}| \leq \frac{1}{2} - \varepsilon$, It seems that we don’t have any information. I don’t know how to proceed