# Still confused with maximum modulus theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I've already asked same question at this site, but I'm still confused with it.

So I hope this is not viewed as duplicate.

Here is the setting:

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic and bounded on unit disk $|z| \lt 1$.

and $f(z) \to 0$ as $z \to 1$ along the upper half of the circle C :$|z-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$.

we want to show that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 1$ along the real-axis.

the hint was to use $F_n(z)=f_n(z) \overline{f_n(\bar{z})}$ , where $f_n(z)=z^n f(z)$.

To show that it approaches to 0 along the real-axis, the author showed that

$|F_n(z)| \lt \varepsilon$  for some given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ on $C$.

and then he said by Maximum modulus theorem, this shows that $|F_n(z)| \lt \varepsilon$ inside $C$.

**This is where I cannot understand, 
As far as I know, if you want to say that 
some analytic function $f$ achieves  its maximum modulus on the boundary,
then it should be continuous on the boundary.
But in this case, we know nothing about the behavior of $f$ at $z=1$, which is the point of the boundary.**

I asked same question to someone else, he said

you don't need to consider the value of $f$ at $z=1$, since we are considering the limit of $f$.

And he argued by example as follows:

if $h(z)$ is an extension of $f(z)$ at $z=1$ letting $h(1)=0$,

and $g(z)$  is a discontinuous extension of $f(z)$ at $z=1$, say $g(1)=10$,

then we can apply MMP to $h(z)$ (Because $h$ is continuous on $C$),

hence $h(z) \to 0$ as $z \to 1$ along the real axis.

But $h(z)$ agrees on the disk with $g(z)$, so $g(z)$ also approaches to $0$ as $z$ on the real-axis,

By the same token, $f(z)$ approaches $0$ as $z$ approaches to $1$ along the real-axis.

with this argument, what I cannot understand are

**1) What if there is no such continous extension of $f$ to $z=1$? then I think the above argument fail.**

2) in above argument,

if we don't need to consider the point $z=1$, then how far can we extend this method?

**In other words, if there are finitely many points $z_1, ..., z_n$, and $f(z) \to 0$ as $z \to z_i$ along the circle for $1 \leq i \leq n$, then it seems that similar argument can be applied. What about infinitely many such points? Is it possible to apply same argument?**

Could you comment what I'm missing or what I misunderstand?

Thank you.

Comment: The earlier question you refer to is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473357/exercises-related-to-maximum-modulus-theorem, is that it?

Comment: @DavidK Yes, it is.

Comment: @glimpser $F_n(z)$ is defined on $C$ except at $z=1$. Using the fact that $f(z) \rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow 1$ along the upper half of the circle, we define $F_n(1)=0$. With this choice, $F_n(z)$ will be continuous on $C$ and its interior.

Comment: @OliverJones That’s what I missed. Thank you.